# Nested list creation from a single list with given range

Tags: python

I have a list `li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
How do I form a nested list for a given range?
lets say if the range is 3 I want the output as `[[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]]`

Comment: 3 is the worst example you could possibly choose because now it is not clear if you want 3 sublists or each sublist to have 3 elements. And what should happen if the list is not cleanly partionable?

Comment: Sorry my bad, 3 is the size of the nested list. The list will always be cleanly partionable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n = 3
new_li = [li[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(li),n)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [itertools' recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

> ````
> from itertools import zip_longest
> def grouper(iterable, n, *, incomplete='fill', fillvalue=None):
>     "Collect data into non-overlapping fixed-length chunks or blocks"
>     # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, fillvalue='x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
>     # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='strict') --> ABC DEF ValueError
>     # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, incomplete='ignore') --> ABC DEF
>     args = [iter(iterable)] * n
>     if incomplete == 'fill':
>         return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
>     if incomplete == 'strict':
>         return zip(*args, strict=True)
>     if incomplete == 'ignore':
>         return zip(*args)
>     else:
>         raise ValueError('Expected fill, strict, or ignore') ```
> ````

Running:

```
>>> li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> list(grouper(li, 3))
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension matches `range`:

```
>>> li = [*range(1, 10)]
>>> [li[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(lst), 3)]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```